# I can't access Project Settings on PhpStorm 2017.2

Tags: phpstorm

Overall I'm really happy with the IDE, but I am trying to access the Project Settings so I can synchronize changes automatically with the server.

Some material on the web says that they are accessible through File -> Settings, but that option isn't available for the version I have.

Does anyone know how to get at them?  I feel really stupid.

Comment: You work with in an FTP server  ?

Comment: No.  I am working locally on my Mac.  The server is also running on my Mac.  I am able to synchronize it and upload changes - everything seems to be working.  But I have to manually synchronize my changes.  I understand that I should be able to sync automatically when the IDE updates my PhpStorm project file.  The online video tutorials are quite dated.

Comment: check Tools/Deployment

Comment: **1)** *"Some material on the web says that they are accessible through File -> Settings, but that option isn't available for the version I have."* **2)** *" I am working locally on my Mac."*. Well .. since you are Mac user  .. you should know by now that every proper app has their preferences accessible via "App name | Preferences". `File | Settings` is for Windows/Linux, on Mac it's `PhpStorm | Preferences`

Comment: Yes, that is usually the case.  It was not the case here.  @MélikZarkouna was able to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't add an Image to a comment i guess this will help :
[image]

Comment: I use RubyMine all the time, but I am a little lost with PhpStorm.  There doesn't seem to be very good documentation about the 2017.2 features.

Comment: I am glad to help you